# Deploying MEF components with the web project that consumes them

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, visual-studio-2012, mef, web-deployment

My apologies if this has already been covered, but I can't find an answer anywhere.

I've got an MVC4 web application that consumes MEF components.  These components live in another project within the same solution, like so:

- My Solution

  1. Web Project
  2. Dll Project defining MEF interfaces (referenced by all)
  3. Dll Project containing an actual MEF class
  4. Another Dll project containing an actual MEF class

The web project references the project containing the MEF interfaces (#2), but not the projects containing the actual MEF classes (#3 & #4), since that's the whole point of the framework.  I have a post-build step on #3 and #4 that copy their compiled assemblies into the bin folder of the web project, and the web project is also marked as dependent on projects #3 and #4.

This works brilliantly on my machine, compiling and shuffling Dlls around, but when I actually have to *deploy* the thing, I'm required to do two steps: deploy the web project like any other, then manually copy the assemblies created by project #3 and #4 onto the server.  Because they're not *really* referenced by the web project, they don't get picked up by the Web Publishing stuff.

I've looked through the Web Publish project settings, and while I can apparently set it to copy every little thing in the project's folder, I can't set it to just copy specific ancillary files.  Is there a way around this besides adding hard references to the #3 and #4 assemblies in the Web Project?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried copying the MEF classes assembly into the ["_bin_deployableAssemblies"](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) folder in your website. For me that worked great

Comment: Thanks, but it's an MVC4 application in VS2012, which I believe doesn't use a _bin_deployableAssemblies folder for bin-deploying things.  I should have mentioned, so I'll edit the question.